# Change font in order email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, magento2.1.0, magento-2.1.4

I am trying to override the default email font with the one from my theme. For instance, if I want to change the font for New Order email (sales), where and how should I make this change?

Thanks

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to go into the templates from the admin area:
Marketing --> Email Templates

... and then you'll want to edit a template using inline CSS formatting.

HTML for email is a whole different animal. Due to security restrictions, you usually cannot load external stylesheets, so everything needs to be done in-line.

Here's a quick code example:

```
<p><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;"><strong>Thanks for your recentl order from our store.  We are thrilled to be shipping it out to you today.</strong></span></p>
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

the best wait to change style in transactional emails with Magento 2 is to use the email style sheet :
`app/design/frontend/<YourVendorName>/<your-theme-name>/web/css/source/_email-base.less`

Official Docs : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Some spécial styles are used in modules, for exemple :

`app/design/frontend/<YourVendorName>/<your-theme-name>/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less`

Magento 2 use Emogrifier (`https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier`) to inject inline styles in tags